# Observe belongsTo relationship in Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am running into this issue with ember data. I would like for `paymentMethodDidChange` to only be called after the payment has been initialized but `paymentMethodDidChange` is called multiple times.

When the payment `isDirty`, I save the object to the backend but I can't do it this way because `paymentMethodDidChange` gets triggered when `payment_method` is set even though it did not change.

How do I set the observer for the `belongsTo` to not fire until after the relationship has been built?

```
App.Payment = DS.Model.extend({
  amount: DS.attr('number'),
  payment_method: DS.belongsTo('payment_method'),

  paymentMethodDidChange: (function() {
    if (!Em.isEmpty(this.get('payment_method')) {
      this.send('becomeDirty');
    }
  }).observes('payment_method').on('init')
})
```

Comment: Can you try to set observes on 'payment_method.isDirty' instead and then send becomeDirty only when the belongsTo model becomes dirty.

Comment: Thanks Deewendra for your reply! I have the issue where neither one (payment or payment_method) isDirty just the relationship has changed. So unfortunately observing payment_method.isDirty would not fire the observer in this case.

Comment: any solution? I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late, but maybe this will help anyone that still have this issue. I had something similar once and solved it by observing the *payment_method.id* instead of *payment_method*.